# OneSignal iOS update issue

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, onesignal

I upgraded OneSignal iOS from version 1.13.3 to 2.8.2 and received the following errors:

1. Code

   ```
   let oneSignal = OneSignal(
       launchOptions: launchOptions,
       appId: appID,
       handleNotification: { (_, userInfo, wasActive) in
           NotificationHandler.handleNotification(
               userInfo: userInfo,
               appWasActive: wasActive
           )
   })
   ```

> Error is "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments"

2. `OneSignal.defaultClient().enable(inAppAlertNotification: false)`

> Error is: Type 'OneSignal' has no member 'defaultClient'

Help me, please.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you create the distribution build? Because I am getting this error. 

"OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension" requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile for the "Release" build configuration in the project editor. (in target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension')